# Software Center Crashing, Im getting annoyed

Tags: wine, software-center

I'm running Ubuntu 15.01 or something like that, I just installed it yesterday.

Anywho, when I try to open the Software center it immediately crashes. Before this whole crashing thing, it wouldn't let me uninstall WINE. Instead I would get a message that read "Failed to load Packing Manager", and it would not uninstall.

What I'm needing to do here: #1) Get software center working correctly.
                             #2) Uninstall WINE.

What I'm ultimately trying to do is use this machine to play World of Warcraft.

Today is Day 2 with Ubuntu, and my wallet is ready to bust open for some Windows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've tried running (sudo apt-get install -f)

I get this in return:

Reading package lists... Error!
E: Problem parsing dependency Depends
E: Error occurred while processing webapp-container (NewVersion2)
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_wily_main_binary-amd64_Packages
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal (Right click your desktop):

```
    sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center
```

If that doesn't work:

```
    sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Open Synaptic File Manager, click reload at the top left. Open the "edit" dropdown at the top of the window and click "fix broken packages."

You most likely removed something that software center required.